# Copying a Method from ViewController to AppDelegate - NULL

Tags: ios, nsstring, null, viewcontroller, appdelegate

Hello i am trying to copy the input from my textfield in the ViewController to my AppDelegate.
No, not vice versa.

As i am trying to do this and i NSLog the gives me this:

```
StruktonTest[8467:11603] (null)
```

Btw, StruktonTest is the name of my Testapp.

Here's my code where i get text in the ViewController:

```
if ([[[self m_textfield] text] length] == 10) {
m_textfield.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", m_textfield.text];
NSLog(@"%@", m_textfield.text);
telefoonnummer = m_textfield.text;
```

I copy it to my AppDelegate.h file like this:

```
@interface  LocationDelegate : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> 
{
UILabel * resultsLabel;
NSString *phonenumber;


}

- (id) initWithLabel:(UILabel*)label;
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName;
-(NSDictionary *)toDictionary;

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *phonenumber;
```

And here's my code from the ViewController, maybe i make the misstake here:

```
@interface LocationTestViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
IBOutlet UILabel * m_significantResultsLabel;
IBOutlet UISwitch * m_significantSwitch;
IBOutlet UISwitch * m_mapSwitch;
IBOutlet MKMapView * m_map;
IBOutlet UITextField * m_textfield;
NSString *String;
IBOutlet UILabel * mobielnummer;
IBOutlet UILabel * deellocatie;
IBOutlet UILabel * welldone;
IBOutlet UILabel * locatiemaps;
IBOutlet UILabel * mapslocatie;
NSString *telefoonnummer;



LocationDelegate * m_significantDelegate;

// location objects
CLLocationManager* m_gpsManager;
CLLocationManager* m_significantManager;
}

-(IBAction) actionSignificant:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) actionMap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) actionLog:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)changrGreeting ;



@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * m_significantResultsLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch * m_significantSwitch;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch * m_mapSwitch;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView * m_map;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *m_textfield;
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet NSString *String;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *mobielnummer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *deellocatie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *welldone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *locatiemaps;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *mapslocatie;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *telefoonnummer;



@end
```

And this is the code from my AppDelegate.m

```
LocationTestViewController*locationTestViewController = [[LocationTestViewController   alloc]init];
phonenumber = locationTestViewController.telefoonnummer;
NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
```

So i'm recieving the NULL when i copy this.
Does anybody know how to fix this. Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
LocationTestViewController*locationTestViewController = [[LocationTestViewController   alloc]init];
phonenumber = locationTestViewController.telefoonnummer;
NSLog(@"%@", phonenumber);
```

Is creating a new instance of LocationTestViewController, then reading the .telefoonnummer field which is obviously empty.

Surely instead of the AppDelegate 'reading' the field, you can use your ViewController to 'give' the field to the AppDelegete?

You could use the NSUserDefaults as a temporary store, or use code like this in your ViewController:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.phoneNumber = self.telefoonnummer;
```

Comment: if i use your code in the ViewController. it gives me another error on the phonenumber. I have defined in in my .h file. Or isn't it a String anymore with your code?

Comment: Sorry, you need to add an #import for your AppDelegate at the top of your ViewController, and also change YourAppDelegate to the name of your app delegate file.

Comment: Property 'phonenumber' not found on object of type 'LocationDelegate'

Comment: According to your code above you have it declared `@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *phonenumber;`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you'd copy and paste. Change the N to a n

Comment: Yes that's true. But it's giving me the error. I don't really know what to do else. Shouldn't it be the appDelegate.telefoonnummer? Or maybe i could send you my projectfiles quickly so you have a can have a look on your own

Comment: Well, i already saw that yes, i saw that immediately. But since i changed that, there is still the eroor

Comment: Shouldn't the @property be (copy)?
Or maybe synthesize it somewhere?

Comment: Upload it somewhere for me and i'll have a peek